# How we can see the version of a particular image at the time of running the container as for golang we use version field

Tags: image, docker, containers, dockerhub

How we can see the version of a particular image at the time of running the container as for golang we use version field.

[Example:
[root@myvm Kirti]# docker container run --rm golang go version
Unable to find image 'golang:latest' locally
Trying to pull repository docker.io/library/golang ...
latest: Pulling from docker.io/library/golang
4a56a430b2ba: Pull complete
4b5cacb629f5: Pull complete
14408c8d4f9a: Pull complete
ea67eaa7dd42: Pull complete
a2a2197e145e: Pull complete
36ac8c11a11f: Pull complete
ecd7d9a67e26: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:90d554b5ae59cb63d2bf42bdfcd60aa1feb4794d9e3a9cbb9d2deb477c088be0
Status: Downloaded newer image for docker.io/golang:latest
go version go1.13 linux/amd64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISSb7.png)

As here go version go1.13 linux/amd64 is a version but is there any way for other images like ubuntu,centos also..or it is only for go language???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> go version go1.13 linux/amd64

This response is not from docker pull command, but from your docker run command.

```
docker container run --rm golang go version
```

And in case of ubuntu and centos, you have `tag` and tag represent the OS version in the image.

As for runtime like nodejs, yes you can run the same command to get version.

```
docker run --rm node:alpine node --version
```